# APC corrupts data after update

Tags: caching, kohana, apc, corrupt

Yesterday I updated APC cache and now sometimes it returns corrupted data.
Not only the data but also the array keys contain weird characters.
Since it only happens sometimes I do not think it is a character issue.

It returns code like this:

```
Array ( [ ����] => Array ( [��~�] => 3 [e, COU] => 0 [ND provi] => 23 [@����~] => 9 ) [WHERE ] => Array ( [��~�] => 13 [e, COU] => 6 [ND provi] => 23 [@����~] => 30 ) ['�@\���R/] => Array ( [��~�] => 134 [e, COU] => 37 [ND provi] => 217 [@����~] => 200 ) [ountry ] => Array ( [��~�] => 2078 [e, COU] => 676 [ND provi] => 914 [@����~] => 1441 ) [total] => Array ( [��~�] => 6517 [e, COU] => 3426 [ND provi] => 1206 [@����~] => 4241 ) [�����~����~ GROU] => Array ( [��~�] => 0 ) )
```

It caches part of the SQL query now that I look at it better.
I am using kohana framework and the APC caching function from them.
What could be the issue here?

Comment: I just found out that it caches the query from a other function. Really strange because I only updated APC cache.

Comment: The problem is not resolved by the way...